# How to remove items from combo store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to remove some items from the end of my comboStore.

What I am trying that is coming correct but in UI all the data is showing.

Suppose I have 500 data. I want to display only 100 data. How to get that.

What I am trying here is

```
var ComboStore = this.store.data.items
var ComboStoreLen = ComboStore.length;
        if (ComboStoreLen > 100) {
                ComboStoreLen.length = 100; // setting the length
            }
```

What I need to restrict in UI. because ComboStore have 500 data.

Comment: Why don't you add a param to your proxy so that the server responds with only 100 records? Why load so much data if you don't need it? Or you do?

Comment: How to add that ?

Comment: Check out the [extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-extraParams) proxy config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restrict in the UI. The UI will always loop over all data that is in the store.

However, you can use a ChainedStore and filter down the records by the index in the original store:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23t1